# how to upload images in wordpress by custom code

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, image-uploading

> i want to upload images via front-end and upload images using wordpress media uploader by custom code and i want result instant to display images

```
<div>
                            <label for="image_url">Picture:</label>
                           <img src="" id="img_url23"/>
                            <input type="hidden" name="image_url" id="image_url" class="regular-text" value="">
                            <input type="button" name="upload-btn" id="upload-btn" class="button-secondary" value="Upload Image">

                        </div>
```

Comment: Hi! While self-answered questions are encouraged here, we still expect both question and answer to follow the guidelines and be on-topic, your question is rather broad and doesn't really explain what is going wrong / what you are having trouble with or what you expect from us, please edit your question to be more detailed

Comment: Your question STILL lacks a actual question, if you hadn't provided the answer yourself, what would you have expected us to answer? Your question is still very broad and you aren't telling us what the included code does / what is wrong with it.

Comment: @Epodax i find out answer and i post it for other user who phase these type of problem

Comment: It doesn't matter, your question and answer still has to follow SO's guidelines.

Comment: @Epodax can you edit my question?

Comment: No, I cannot, that's your own job.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121617/discussion-between-vivek-and-epodax).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
 <?php
                      wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
                      wp_enqueue_media();//enqueue these default wordpress file

                            ?>
        <div>
                                <label for="image_url">Picture:</label>
  <img scr="" id="image_url2">//for show instant image
                                <input type="hidden" name="image_url2" id="image_url_2" class="regular-text" value="">
                                <input type="button" name="upload-btn" id="upload-btn-2" class="button-secondary" value="Upload Image">

        </div>

---------------------------------javascript-------------------------------

    $('#upload-btn-2').click(function(e) {
                                    e.preventDefault();
                                    var image = wp.media({ 
                                        title: 'Upload Image',
                                        // mutiple: true if you want to upload multiple files at once
                                        multiple: false
                                    }).open()
                                    .on('select', function(e){
                                        // This will return the selected image from the Media Uploader, the result is an object
                                        var uploaded_image = image.state().get('selection').first();
                                        // We convert uploaded_image to a JSON object to make accessing it easier
                                        // Output to the console uploaded_image
                                        console.log(uploaded_image);
                                        var image_url = uploaded_image.toJSON().url;
                                        // Let's assign the url value to the input field
                                        $('#image_url_2').val(image_url);
                                        $('#image_url2').attr('src',image_url);

                                    });
                                });
```

Comment: Is this really an answer?

Comment: Hi! While self-answered questions are encouraged here, we still expect both question and answer to follow the guidelines and be on-topic, your answer is purely code and it doesn't help or explain OP or future visitors what you have changed or what they were doing wrong, please update your answer to help explain what is exactly going on in your answer.

Comment: you can try this code for upload media from front end